# How to access the scope of the directive in Jasmine Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I cant get the scope of my directive (another option is that I get the scope but my function is not there). I am using Jasmine over Karma.

**My directive:**

```
angular.module('taskApp').directive('nkAlertDir', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        template: "<span>{{msg}}</span>",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.values = {
                canvas: canvasSize,
                radius: size,
                center: canvasSize / 2
            };

            $http.get('someUrl')
                .suncces(function (data) {
                    scope.msg = data;
                })
                .error(function (err) {
                    //there is always be error because this url does nor exist
                    //but this is not the point in this exercise
                });

            scope.returnNumbers = function () {
                return [2, 2];
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**My test:**

```
describe('Unit: Directives', function () {

    var element;
    var scope;

    beforeEach(module('taskApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {

        scope = $rootScope;
        element = angular.element('<div nk-alert-dir></div>');

        scope.size = 100;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should bind an alert message of "task added!"', function () {

        var dirScope = element.isolateScope();
        console.log(dirScope);
    });
});
```

Somehow I always get the dirScope is undefined 
I have tried this:

- replaced the `digest()` in `$apply()`
- replaced the `$rootScope` in `$rootScope.$new()`

Comment: Immediate observation: your directive is named nkAlertDir and the test calls for an element attribute 'nk-alert'. I would have assumed you would need 'nk-alert-dir' to call on your directive for scope to be defined.

Comment: I am sorry I uploaded version which i changed the name when I copied the code.. not a smart move I guess but this two have the same name

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an isolated scope in your directive, so `element.isolateScope()` is going to return undefined.

Try just accessing the scope:  `element.scope()`

If you want an isolate scope on your directive, then you have to set the `scope` property of your directive definition object to a JS object and add the properties there.  Then you'd be able to use `element.isolateScope` to get access to the isolate scope.

```
return {
        template: "<span>{{msg}}</span>",
        replace: true,
        scope : {},   // Any properties you want to pass in to the directive on scope would get defined here
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.values = {
                canvas: canvasSize,
                radius: size,
                center: canvasSize / 2
            };

            $http.get('someUrl')
                .suncces(function (data) {
                    scope.msg = data;
                })
                .error(function (err) {
                    //there is always be error because this url does nor exist
                    //but this is not the point in this exercise
                });

            scope.returnNumbers = function () {
                return [2, 2];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I get a scope but I dont get the objects I defined on the scope non of my functions and variables are on this scope, its clean new scope.
can you explain why this is not isolated scope?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I found out how to access scope. I created  new controller for my directive and was accessing the controller throw the controller injector function.